# Change of variable of integration in the geodesics' differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

Suppose we have the following system of differential equations (which correspond to the geodesics of a torus)

$$
\begin{cases}
     \frac{d^2u}{dt^2} + (\frac{d\phi}{dt})^2 \sin u (a+\cos u) = 0
\\   \frac{d^2\phi}{dt^2} - 2\frac{du}{dt}\frac{d\phi}{dt} \frac{\sin u}{a+\cos u} = 0
\end{cases}
$$

If I am not looking for meridians, I believe that I can write $u(\phi)$. Now, can I choose $t=\phi$ and write

$$
\begin{cases}
     \frac{d^2u}{d\phi^2} +  \sin u (a+\cos u) = 0
\\    - 2\frac{du}{d\phi} \frac{\sin u}{a+\cos u} = 0
\end{cases}
$$
and the $u(\phi)$ that are solutions to this correspond to the non-meridian geodesics?

This may be a very basic question, but my background in differential equations is (sadly) quite poor.

Comment: I've not checked your work, but I highly doubt you can solve the ODE for the geodesics on a torus in closed form. When I assign this question, I'm looking for a qualitative discussion of the geodesics based on Clairaut's relation describing geodesics on a surface of revolution.

Comment: @TedShifrin Right. But in this case I want to find the values of $a$ (even if implicitly) such that there exists a geodesic such that $u\in [-\pi/4,\pi/4]$ (and $u$ attains all this values) and such that $u(\phi)$ has period $2\pi$, so I was trying to simplify the ODEs and then somehow use this information about $u$ in order to find an equation which determines $a$.

Comment: @TedShifrin I do not see how I can do it using qualitative arguments such as the Clairaut relation

Comment: I did not know what your ultimate goal was. From those differential equations you can derive an explicit integral formula for $\phi$ as a function of $u$. Whether you can compute the integral in closed form is another question. See, for example, exercise 23 on p. 78 of my notes. You can also find this integral formula in DoCarmo's undergraduate text. With some numerical work, you should be able to apply an intermediate value theorem argument to conclude that you will get such closed geodesics with period $2\pi/k$ for $k\ge 2$ or so.